# Nested parallel stream execution in Java - findAny() randomly fails

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

The following code throws the *IllegalArgumentException* in every 10-15 try for the **same** input:

```
        AllDirectedPaths<Vertex, Edge> allDirectedPaths = new AllDirectedPaths<>(graph);
        List<GraphPath<Vertex, Edge>> paths = allDirectedPaths.getAllPaths(entry, exit, true, null);


        return paths.parallelStream().map(path -> path.getEdgeList().parallelStream()
                .map(edge -> {
                    Vertex source = edge.getSource();
                    Vertex target = edge.getTarget();

                    if (source.containsInstruction(method, instructionIndex)) {
                        return source;
                    } else if (target.containsInstruction(method, instructionIndex)) {
                        return target;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }).filter(Objects::nonNull)).findAny().flatMap(Stream::findAny)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Given trace refers to no vertex in graph!"));
```

The idea of the code is to find a vertex that wraps a certain instruction (see `containsInstruction()`), whereas the vertex is on at least one path from the `entry` to the `exit` vertex. I'm aware that the code is not optimal in terms of performance (every intermediate vertex on a path is looked up twice), but that doesn't matter.

The input is simply a trace (String) from which the `method` and `instructionIndex` can be derived. All other variables are *fixed* in that sense. Moreover, the method `containsInstruction()` doesn't have any side effects.

Does it matter where to put the 'findAny()' stream operation? Should I place it directly following the filter operation? Or are nested parallel streams the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.flatMap(path ->  ... )` and remove `.flatMap(Stream::findAny)`.

Your code doesn't work because the first `findAny()` returns a stream that is always non null, but that might hold `null` elements.

Then, when you apply the second `findAny()` by means of the `Optional.flatMap(Stream::findAny)` call, this last find operation might return an empty `Optional`, as the result of ending up with a `null` element of the inner stream.

This is how the code should look:

```
return paths.stream()
    .flatMap(path -> path.getEdgeList().stream()
        .map(edge -> 
             edge.getSource().containsInstruction(method, instructionIndex) ?
             edge.getSource()                                               :
             edge.getTarget().containsInstruction(method, instructionIndex) ?
             edge.getTarget()                                               :
             null)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull))
    .findAny()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("whatever"));
```

Note aside: why parallel streams? There doesn't seem to be CPU bound tasks in your pipeline. Besides, parallel streams create a lot of overhead. They are useful in very few scenarios, i.e. tens of thousands of elements and intensive CPU operations along the pipeline

---

**EDIT:** As suggested in the comments, the `map` and `filter` operations of the inner stream could be safely moved to the outer stream. This way, readability is improved and there's no difference performance-wise:

```
return paths.stream()
    .flatMap(path -> path.getEdgeList().stream())
    .map(edge -> 
         edge.getSource().containsInstruction(method, instructionIndex) ?
         edge.getSource()                                               :
         edge.getTarget().containsInstruction(method, instructionIndex) ?
         edge.getTarget()                                               :
         null)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findAny()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("whatever"));
```

Another note: maybe refactoring the code inside `map` to a method of the `Edge` class would be better, so that the logic to return either the source, the target or `null` is in the class that already has all the information.

Comment: I will try it out. I simply used parallel streams because it seems natural to me. It is one of the few use cases where no shared variables slow down / hinder parallel execution.

Comment: @auermich Always measure and microbenchmark carefully before taking such decisions. Most sure you'll notice it's slower with parallel streams

Comment: Just for clarification of the original problem. The inner map may produces single paths of the form [null,..,null] where the filter results in empty lists and findAny() might pick such empty Optional resulting in the exception?

Comment: @auermich Yes, the problem is that the first `findAny()` returns a `Stream` that is always non null, but that might have some null element inside it. So then, when you apply the second `findAny()` call, you might end up with one of these null elements

Comment: I think, it will be more readable when keeping the nested code as small as possible. The `map` and `filter` steps do not need to be attached to the inner stream expression. They could be chained after `.flatMap(path -> path.getEdgeList().stream())`

Comment: There’s no difference performance-wise to be expected, it’s just affecting readability. Only stateful operations like `sorted` or `distinct` would be different, but that should be obvious, as moving those would be a semantic change. When the intermediate operations needed access to `path` they had to stay in the inner operation.